# Training model for a board game with large actions space

Tags: deep-rl, game-ai

that has a NxM board, and players take turns putting their "dots" on the board a X,Y coordinate, taking up the space. When a few connected dots surround an opponent dot(s), the surrounding dots create a polygon which is taken (no dots can be put on it) and counting the surrounded dots as points. The game ends when less than 20% of the board remains available and the winner is the player who has more points.

[image]

So my question is, how do I approach the training of an agent for this game? I've trained a model on a much simpler "fighting" game, with 3 possible actions, stamina and HP to acceptable results using this setup:

```
# Define the game environment
NUM_OF_ACTIONS = 3
NUM_OF_EPISODES = 20

# Define the neural network model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_OF_ACTIONS, activation='softmax')
])

# Define the loss function and optimizer
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
```

And this code for training each step:

```
action_probs = model.predict(np.array([state]))
        action = np.random.choice(NUM_OF_ACTIONS, p=action_probs[0])

        # Take the chosen action and observe the resulting state and reward
        next_state, reward, done = env.step(action)
        print(f"{reward=}, {done=}")
        # Train the model on the observed transition
        train_step(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
```

- But in setup I don't see a way to limit the action space when coordinates become unavailable - how do I disable coords as they become unavailable?
- Do I need to train the agent to play on each map size (NxM) I want him to play on?

Comment: Welcome to AI SE. I'd like to propose several points of improvement for your post. First, limit your post to one question. Second, refrain from questions on programming advice etc, you can better ask those over at [DS SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Lastly, put your one specific question in the title of your post.